# Children of Parent to Parent Relationship

Tags: relationships

I have what I thought was an obvious task, but I must be doing something incorrect or have encountered a bug.

I have a Parent relationship to another Parent. The parents are teams, and sometimes teams partner, so through the relationship of parent to parent, when looking at one team, I can show the applicable partner team(s)

In my template, I am outputting the first parent (team)/children (members) without issue.

But when I try to output the children of the relationship team, it works, but only shows one entry no matter what parameters I play with. It’s not looping through showing them all.

I've tried siblings, but then I get the results from any relation, not the direct one I am wanting. This simple enough, yet not working.

```
{rel_partner_teams}
  <div class="member_img">
    {rel_partner_teams:rel_team_members:file_member_photo}
  </div>
{/rel_partner_teams}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another tag pair, as each tag pair loops through only *that one* relationship. You need to loop through another set of relationships within each relationship.

```
{rel_partner_teams}
    {rel_partner_teams:rel_team_members}
        <div class="member_img">
            {rel_partner_teams:rel_team_members:file_member_photo}
        </div>
    {/rel_partner_teams:rel_team_members}
{/rel_partner_teams}
```

Also, just to clarify language - there is no "parent-to-parent" relationship here, even though you are relating each entry to entries in the same channel. If an entry is selected in a relationship field, it becomes the "child" of the entry it was selected in. So your example is actually "parent to child to child." :)

Comment: Thanks Derek. I had come to see my error late last night after stepping away from it for a while. Thanks for confirming I employed it correctly this time. As well for the correcting my misused terminology. I was thinking about the whole thing wrong at first. Cheers!